# BST in javascript using reference objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I found this algorithm from Data structures and algorithms in javascript. For the insertion method, there are two references to the root (current and parent). My question is, why can't i change both current and parent to this.root? They both point to this.root. The code does not work properly when I do that however

```
'use strict';

var BST = function() {
  this.root = null;

//embed _Node inside BST so it comes with when BST is created
  this._Node = function(data, left, right) {
    this.data = data;
    this.count = 1;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  };

  this._Node.prototype.show = function() {
    return this.data;
  };

  this._Node.prototype.showCount = function() {
    return this.count;
  }
};


BST.prototype.insert = function(data) {
  //use this data for a new node
  var n = new this._Node(data, null, null);
  //if root is null, put this new node and its data into root
  if (this.root === null) {
    this.root = n;
  }
  else {
    //find a child position for this node
    var current = this.root;
    var parent;
    while (true) {
      parent = current;
      if (data < current.data) {
        current = current.left;
        if (current === null) {
          parent.left = n;
          break;
        }
      }
      else {
        current = current.right;
        if (current === null) {
          parent.right = n;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var nums = new BST(); 
nums.insert(23); 
nums.insert(45); 
nums.insert(16); 
nums.insert(37); 
nums.insert(3); 
nums.insert(99); 
nums.insert(22);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current` does not refer to `this.root` throughout the entire algorithm.

It is initialized as `this.root`, but then it is quickly reassigned to either `current = current.left;` or `current = current.right;`. From that moment on `current` is no longer `this.root`. It is either `this.root.left` or `this.root.right`.

On the next iteration of the while loop it will get reassigned again, but it will never be `this.root` again, since it is alway being reassigned to a child node of `current`.

`parent` is similar, being `this.root` only on the first iteration. On each subsequent iteration it is reassigned by `parent = current;` and since `current is no longer`this.root`,`parent`won't be`this.root` either.

Answer (score 0):

`parent` is used just to hold reference of the previous node, you create new node `n` and then find it's position in the tree, once `current` becomes `null`, you have found the target position for node `n`, you need to assign it as child (`left` or `right`) to the `parent` node